# If magnetic field is a bivector, then what is the pole strength?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

I have an intuition that magnetic fields are bivectors. While trying to derive some equations with bivectors, I arrived at this formula
$$F=\frac{q_{m_a}q_{m_b}}{r^2}\hat r$$
So we have,
$$F=q_mB$$
Now, what is pole strength? It maps bivectors to vectors?

**Edit Note:**
I want to generalize magnetism to n-dimensions

**Edit 2:**
Do I need to consider magnetic field as pseudovectors i.e. grade-(n-1) multivector?
For 3d bivector, For 4d trivector such that? But this means magnetic field is a vector in 2d? Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Geometric Algebra approach to electromagnetism (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5002)) finds that the electromagnetic field is a *bivector* in 4D spacetime. We can shift our point of view to a specific 3D reference frame by multiplying everything by the time vector (called a *spacetime split*), which splits the electromagnetic field into a *vector* electric field and a *trivector* magnetic field.

We first express 4D spacetime vectors as a combination of 4 unit basis vectors in each direction: $e_t$, $e_x$, $e_y$, $e_z$. (I'm not using the proper notation here, to shorten the exposition. See the paper linked above for a more rigorous and systematic explanation.)

The electromagnetic bivector then has six components: $e_xe_t$, $e_ye_t$, $e_ze_t$, $e_ye_z$, $e_xe_z$, $e_xe_y$. Each of these is a geometric product of two of the unit vectors.

We multiply the whole thing by the constant $e_t$. Since $e_t^2=1$, the $e_t$ component disappears on the first three, and we get: $e_x$, $e_y$, $e_z$, and $e_ye_ze_t$, $e_xe_ze_t$, $e_xe_ye_t$. The vector part with components $e_x$, $e_y$, $e_z$ is the electric field.

Because Gibbs' vector algebra can't cope with trivectors, we convert the other three components to a vector by taking the *dual*. This is equivalent to the Hodge star operation used in differential geometry, and can be done in Geometric Algebra by dividing by the constant pseudoscalar $I=e_xe_ye_ze_t$. Since $e_x^2=e_y^2=e_z^2=-1$, this has the effect of cancelling any components that were there, and inserting any components that weren't. So $(e_ye_ze_t)(e_xe_ye_ze_t)^{-1}=e_x$, and so on.

The electromagnetic field is thus written $Fe_t=E+BI$. $F$ is the bivector field, $e_t$ is the unit vector in the time direction that expresses everything in a particular inertial reference frame, $E$ is the electric field 3-vector, $B$ is the magnetic field 3-vector, and $I$ is the pseudoscalar used to convert a trivector $BI$ to a vector in 3D.

The expression $E+BI$ expresses the electromagnetic field as a 'Complex' vector with Real and Imaginary components. This is the basis of the [Riemann-Silberstein vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Silberstein_vector). Although $I$ acts *somewhat* like the unit imaginary in that $I^2=-1$, it has a *geometric* meaning that means that when you change to a different reference frame, it rotates $E$ and $B$ components into each other, maintaining reference-frame independence. The original Riemann-Silberstein approach only worked in a particular reference frame, because it treated $i$ as an imaginary scalar, that doesn't transform when we switch coordinates.

Although in our universe we only have electric charges and currents, the equations have a *duality symmetry* in which we can multiply $E+BI$ by $e^{I\theta}$ and get another solution, switching and mixing the roles of $E$ and $B$. The electric current is a 4-vector $J_e$ (which we can do the spacetime split on to get a scalar electric charge and 3-vector electric current), the magnetic equivalent is the dual to this which is a trivector. For convenience, we can use $I$ to express the current $J=J_e+J_mI$, where $J_m$ is a 4-vector, which can be split into a magnetic monopole charge, and a magnetic current.

The duality symmetry only applies in a vaccuum, in our universe, because the coupling to matter breaks the symmetry. We only have electric charges, the imaginary component of $J=J_e+J_mI$ is always zero. But according to the paper I linked above, the duality symmetry is part of the larger electroweak symmetry that exists prior to the separation of electromagnetism and the weak nuclear force.

In summary: yes, in the underlying physics the electromagnetic field is a 4D *bivector*, but in order to squeeze it into the straitjacket of Gibbs' 3D vector algebra we have to split it into vector electric and trivector magnetic components, and then dualise the trivector magnetic component to turn it into a 3D vector field. These manipulations have nothing to do with the underlying physics - they are purely done so that we can use 3-vectors.

Similarly, the unified electric-magnetic current is a 'Complex' mix of vector and trivector components. To work with 3D Gibbs' vectors we again split it up and dualise it artificially.

If you're interested in an alternate geometric viewpoint on vectors, bivectors, spinors, and so on, then the Space-Time Algebra/Geometric Algebra approach is worth looking at. It doesn't do anything the mathematicians didn't already know (they're just Real Clifford algebras), but it gives a geometric Real-number interpretation that physicists find a lot easier to work with, and provides a lot of interesting insights into what the somewhat opaque mathematical abstractions really mean. For example, all the weird imaginary numbers in quantum physics get replaced by Real geometric entities like bivectors and pseudoscalars (plane elements and volume elements). Spinors are just the even subalgebra of a Geometric Algebra, and have a comparatively simple and intuitive geometric meaning. It takes a while to get up to speed on the mindset - you effectively have to go back and relearn vectors from scratch - but I've found it well worth the effort.

Comment: Can this be progressed to 2d and 4d?

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic monopole charge is a pseudoscalar.
(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscalar )

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#Tensor_formulation

The magnetic field [magnetic induction] B in Gauss's Law for magnetism (and in Faraday's Law] is a bivector,
like the electric field (call it D) is in Gauss' Law and Faraday's Law.

(These are associated with fluxes.)

However, the magnetic field (call it H) in the force law (and in Ampere-Maxwell)
is a [pseudo-]vector, like the electric field E is in the force law (and in Faraday).

(These are associated with circulation.)

Of course, force is a vector.

(Depending on your starting point,
maybe the force law should be written as an equation of one-forms).

So, it might be better to think of it as
$$F=q_m H,$$
the product of a pseudoscalar and a pseudovector.

Comment: So u mean the force equation cannot be denoted in form of bivector?

Comment: @JRBros For the force on a magnetic monopole, I think you would need the 3D-Hodge dual of the magnetic-field-bivector. For the force on an electric charge, you would use the magnetic-field-bivector contracted with the electric-charge's velocity-vector.

Comment: What is the 3d hodge star operator? And how should i use it?

Comment: @JRBros The 3D-Hodge dual is how we associate a vector with the cross-product of two vectors. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Three_dimensions ) For magnetism, it is how B and H are related (a constitutive relation using the volume element and something to describe a medium [possibly vacuum]).

Comment: @JRBros Possibly useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/692414/electromagnetism-using-differential-forms-question-about-names-and-units

Comment: How to make it 2d? pseudoscalars are 3d

Comment: @JRBros what do you mean “make it 2D”? Electromagnetism in 2spatial dimensions?  (seems like a different question from what you initially asked.) Pseudoscalars are associated with the volume element… so one could call it 3d in the usual case of 3 dimensional space.

Comment: I mean the whole reason I want bivectors is to generalize the whole problem to n-dimension. But only being defined in 3d will make my goal pointless. I editted the question

Comment: @JRBros Note that a pseudoscalar has one component. You might think of it as three dimensional in 3D because of the volume element... but there is still only one component. This answers the original question (and the question in the title) about the nature of the pole strength.... presumably in ordinary electrodynamics (with monopoles) in 3D space. (In your original question, you never specified your goal to generalize to n-dimensions.)

Comment: Yeah but my inner goal was to make it to n dimensions. Sorry for not mentioning it :(. But without this constraint, I'd have given this answer the correct answer

Comment: @JRBros Umm... ok. The answer that you finally did accept did not answer your question (given in the title and in the body of the question) and did not make reference to your force law. It talks about the field and the sources (which would be the answer to a different question)... not the force law. Well... Good luck.

Comment: It gave me an idea that magnetic field is a pseudo vector with grade (n-1) that is what I was struggling with. I thought it was a bivector and it is only true for 3d. For 4d it is a trivector  and works with the pseudo scalar you talked about